# is form tag position affect user input when processed?

Tags: php

**Problem:** input not posted when processed. My hypothesis is the placement for the form tag position is invalid, the query able to pick up data from database but not from  user input. try move form tag position but doesn't help.

**Code for the input:**

```
<?php
session_start();



<?php
            include './auth.php';
            // check available room
            
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT r.room_id, (r.total_room-br.total) as availableroom from room as r LEFT JOIN ( 
            
                                    SELECT roombook.room_id, sum(roombook.totalroombook) as total from roombook where roombook.booking_id IN 
                                        (
                                            SELECT b.booking_id as bookingID from booking as b 
                                            where 
                                            (b.checkin_date between '".$datestart."' AND '".$dateend."') 
                                            OR 
                                            (b.checkout_date between '".$dateend."' AND '".$datestart."')
                                            
                                            
                                        )
                                    
                                    group by roombook.room_id
                                    )
                                    as br
                 
                 ON r.room_id = br.room_id");
            echo mysqli_error($conn);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo "<p><b>Choose Your Room</b></p><hr class=\"line\">";
        the focus row       print "             <form action=\"guestform.php\" method=\"post\">\n";
                
                        
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                
                            
                    if($row['availableroom'] != null && $row['availableroom'] > 0  )
                    {
                        
                        $sub_result = mysqli_query($conn,"select room.* from room where room.room_id = ".$row['room_id']." ");
                        
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($sub_result) > 0)
                        {
                            
                            while($sub_row = mysqli_fetch_array($sub_result)){
                            
                            
                            print "                 <p><h4>".$sub_row['room_name']."</h4></p>\n";
                            print "                 <div class=\"row\">\n";
                            print "                 \n";
                            print "                     <div class=\"large-4 columns\">\n";
                            print "                         <img src=\"".$sub_row['imgpath']."\"></img>\n";
                            print "                     <p><span class=\"fontgrey\">Occupancy : </span> ".$sub_row['occupancy']."<br>\n";
                            print "                     <span class=\"fontgrey\">Size : </span> ".$sub_row['size']."\n";
                            print "                     <br><span class=\"fontgrey\">View : </span> ".$sub_row['view']."</p>\n";
                            print "                     </div>\n";
                            print "                     <div class=\"large-4 columns\">\n";
                            print " the focus row       <p ><span class=\"fontgrey\">Total Adult</span></p><input type=\"text\" name=\"total_adult\"><br>\n"; 
                            print " the focus row                   <p ><span class=\"fontgrey\">Total Children</span></p><input type=\"text\" name=\"total_children\" ><br>\n"; 
                            print "\n";
                            print "                     </div>\n";
                            print "                     <div class=\"large-4 columns\">\n";
                            print " the focus row       <p ><span class=\"fontgrey\">Rate : MYR </span></p><input type=\"text\" name=\"rate\" value=\"".$sub_row['weekday']."\"><span class=\"fontgrey\">/person</span><br>\n";
                            print " the focus row       <p ><span class=\"fontgrey\">Rate : MYR </span></p><input type=\"text\" name=\"chrate\" value=\"".$sub_row['cweekday']."\"><span class=\"fontgrey\">/person</span><br>\n";
                            print "                     <span style=\"text-align:right;\">".$row['availableroom']." room available</span>\n";
                            print "                     </p>\n";
                            print "                         <div class=\"row\">\n";
                            print "                             <div class=\"large-11 columns\">\n";
                            print "                                 <label class=\"fontcolor\">\n";
                            print "                                     <select  class=\"no_of_room\" name=\"qtyroom".$sub_row['room_id']."\" id=\"room".$sub_row['room_id']."\" onChange=\"selection(".$sub_row['room_id'].")\"  style=\"width:100%; color:black; height:45px;\" ;\">\n";
                            print "                                         <option  value=\"0\">0</option>\n";
                                                                             
$i = 1;
                                                                             
while($i <= $row['availableroom'])
                                                                             
{
                            print "                                         <option value=\"".$i."\">".$i."</option>\n";    
                                                                            $i = $i+1;
                                                                            }
                            print "                                     </select>\n";
                            print "                                 </label>\n";
                            print "                             </div>\n";
                            print "                             <div class=\"large-1 columns\">\n";
                            print "<input type=hidden name=\"selectedroom".$sub_row['room_id']."\"  id=\"selectedroom".$sub_row['room_id']."\" value=\"".$sub_row['room_id']."\">";
                            print "<input type=hidden name=\"room_name".$sub_row['room_id']."\" id=\"room_name".$sub_row['room_id']."\" value=\"".$sub_row['room_name']."\">";
                            print "                             </div>\n";
                            print "                         </div>\n";
                            print "                     </div>\n";
                            print "                     \n";
                            print "                 </div>\n";
                            print "                 \n";
                            print "             <hr>";
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    else if($row['availableroom'] == null ){
                        $sub_result2 = mysqli_query($conn,"select room.* from room where room.room_id = ".$row['room_id']." ");
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($sub_result2) > 0)
                        {
                            while($sub_row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sub_result2)){
                            
                            print "                 <p><h4>".$sub_row2['room_name']."</h4></p>\n";
                            print "                 <div class=\"row\">\n";
                            print "                 \n";
                            print "                     <div class=\"large-4 columns\">\n";
                            print "                         <img src=\"".$sub_row2['imgpath']."\"></img>\n";
                            print "                     <p><span class=\"fontgrey\">Occupancy : </span> ".$sub_row2['occupancy']."<br>\n";
                            print "                     <span class=\"fontgrey\">Size : </span> ".$sub_row2['size']."\n";
                            print "                     <br><span class=\"fontgrey\">View : </span> ".$sub_row2['view']."</p>\n";
                            print "                     </div>\n";
                            print "                     <div class=\"large-4 columns\">\n";
                            print "  the focus row      <p ><span class=\"fontgrey\">Total Adult</span></p><input type=\"text\" name=\"total_adult\"><br>\n";
                            print "  the focus row      <p ><span class=\"fontgrey\">Total Children</span></p><input type=\"text\" name=\"total_children\"><br>\n";
                            print "\n";
                            print "                     </div>\n";
                            print "                     <div class=\"large-4 columns\">\n";
                            print "  the focus row      <p ><span class=\"fontgrey\">Rate : MYR </span></p><input type=\"text\" name=\"rate\" value=\"".$sub_row2['weekday']."\"><span class=\"fontgrey\">/person</span><br>\n";
                            print "  the focus row      <p ><span class=\"fontgrey\">Rate : MYR </span></p><input type=\"text\" name=\"chrate\" value=\"".$sub_row2['cweekday']."\"><span class=\"fontgrey\">/person</span><br>\n";
                            print "                     <div><span style=\"text-align:right;\">".$sub_row2['total_room']." room available</span></div>\n";
                            print "                     </p>\n";
                            print "                         <div class=\"row\">\n";
                            print "                             <div class=\"large-11 columns\">\n";
                            print "                                 <label class=\"fontcolor\">\n";
                            print "                                     <select  class=\"no_of_room\" name=\"qtyroom".$sub_row2['room_id']."\"  id=\"room".$sub_row2['room_id']."\" onChange=\"selection(".$sub_row2['room_id'].")\" style=\"width:100%; color:black; height:45px;\" >\n";
                            print "                                         <option value=\"0\">0</option>\n";
                                                                            $i = 1;
                                                                            while($i <= $sub_row2['total_room'])
                                                                            {
                            print "                                         <option value=\"".$i."\">".$i."</option>\n";    
                                                                            $i = $i+1;
                                                                            }
                            print "                                     </select>\n";
                            print "                                 </label>\n";
                            print "                             </div>\n";
                            print "                             <div class=\"large-1 columns\">\n";
                            print "<input type hidden name=\"selectedroom".$sub_row2['room_id']."\" value=\"".$sub_row2['room_id']."\">";
                            print "<input  type=hidden name=\"room_name".$sub_row2['room_id']."\" value=\"".$sub_row2['room_name']."\">";
                            //print "               <button type=\"submit\"  class=\"book button small\" style=\"background-color:#2ecc71; width:100%; height:45px; !important;\" >Book</button>\n";    
                            print "                             </div>\n";
                            print "                         </div>\n";
                            print "                     </div>\n";
                            print "                     \n";
                            print "                 </div>\n";
                            print "                 \n";
                            print "             <hr>";
                            }
                            
                        }       
                    }   
                }
                        

                    
    the focus row               print "<button type=\"submit\" id=\"submit-form\" class=\"hidden\" style=\"display:none\">Book</button>\n";
    the focus row               print " </form>";   

            }
            
                            
            
        ?>
```

From above code **please find the "the focus row"** where the input should be.

Then `guestform.php` also contain comment where you should focus on.

```
<?php
session_start();
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
include './auth.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['room_id'])){
                    
                    $_SESSION['room_id'] = array();
                    
                    $_SESSION['roomname'] = array();
                    
                    $_SESSION['roomqty'] = array();
                    $_SESSION['total_adult'] = array(); the focus row
                    $_SESSION['total_children'] = array(); the focus row
                    $_SESSION['rate'] = array(); the focus row
                    $_SESSION['chrate'] = array(); the focus row
                    $_SESSION['ind_rate'] = array();
                    $_SESSION['total_amount'] = 0;
                    $_SESSION['deposit'] = 0;
                    }

            $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from room");
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            
                    $count = 0;
                    
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    
                        if (isset($_POST["qtyroom".$row['room_id'].""])   && !empty($_POST["qtyroom".$row['room_id'].""])  )
                        {
                            $_SESSION['room_id'][$count] = $_POST["selectedroom".$row['room_id'].""];
                            $_SESSION['roomqty'][$count] = $_POST["qtyroom".$row['room_id'].""];
                            $_SESSION['roomname'][$count] = $_POST["room_name".$row['room_id'].""];
            the focus row   $_SESSION['total_adult'][$count] = $_POST["total_adult"];
            the focus row   $_SESSION['total_children'][$count] = $_POST["total_children"];
            the focus row   $_SESSION['rate'][$count] = $_POST["rate"];
            the focus row   $_SESSION['chrate'][$count] = $_POST["chrate"];
                            $_SESSION['ind_rate1'][$count] = ((int)$_SESSION['rate'][$count]   * (int) $_SESSION['total_adult'][$count]);
                            $_SESSION['ind_rate2'][$count] = ((int)$_SESSION['chrate'][$count] * (int)$_SESSION['total_children'][$count]);
                            $_SESSION['total1'] =  ( $_SESSION['ind_rate1'][$count])  ;
                            $_SESSION['total2'] =  ( $_SESSION['ind_rate2'][$count])  ;
                            $_SESSION['total_amount'] = $_SESSION['ind_rate2'][$count]+ $_SESSION['ind_rate1'][$count] ;
                            $_SESSION['deposit'] = $_SESSION['total_amount'] * 0.15;
                            
                            $count = $count + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    
                }




?>
```

**The query**

```
<?php
$_SESSION['booking_id'] = mysqli_insert_id($conn);    
$count = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['room_id'] as &$value0 ) {
$l="INSERT INTO roombook ( booking_id, room_id, totalroombook, total_adult, total_children, rate, chrate, id) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['booking_id']."','".$value0."','".$_SESSION['roomqty'][$count]."','".$_SESSION['total_adult'][$count]."','".$_SESSION['total_children'][$count]."','".$_SESSION['rate'][$count]."','".$_SESSION['chrate'][$count]."',NULL)";
mysqli_query($conn,$l);
        
$count = $count+1;
echo mysqli_error($conn);
print_r ($l);
} 
?>
```

**Test run Query return :**
[image]

**Expected Query Return:**

`INSERT INTO roombook ( booking_id, room_id, totalroombook, total_adult, total_children, rate, chrate, id) VALUES ('34','1','1','1','1','1','1',NULL)`

**Improve after comment request**

**var_dump($_SESSION);**

`["total_night"]=> string(1) "1" ["room_id"]=> &array(1) { [0]=> &string(1) "1" } ["roomname"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "Standard Room(QUAD)" } ["roomqty"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["total_adult"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["total_children"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["rate"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "499" } ["chrate"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "299" } ["ind_rate"]=> array(0) { } ["total_amount"]=> string(6) "845.88" ["deposit"]=> string(4) "1000" ["ind_rate1"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["ind_rate2"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["total1"]=> int(0) ["total2"]=> int(0) ["booking_id"]=> int(35)`

Comment: Hi fzstyle, can you please do `var_dump($_SESSION);` and paste output here?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch hai. please check updated question.

Comment: So much code! The trick is to identify where you are having a problem, and only post the relevant part.

Comment: @Ibu dear sir. thanks for helping, i agree with the length of the code is too long, but FYI all the code is related to my  problem.  i already mention in detail where to focus the most but again all code is related to each other. if i remove some of the code, this will be such a pain for others to help me. hope u understand what i'm try to describe. ask you requested i remove some of the code but if that still make u hard tell me where to remove code that u think it is not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the form tag positioning can affect the submitted data from the browser.

However your main issue appears to be that you are iterating over multiple database result rows, and creating form elements per row with the duplicate `name` attributes.

The duplicate form field name submission results in your form being submitted with only the **last** form fields values of the same name being submitted.

For example:

```
<form method="post">
   <input name="a" type="text" value="1"/>
   <input name="a" type="text" value="2"/>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Will result in PHP receiving

```
$_POST = ['a' => 2]
```

It appears that this was partially addressed in a few form fields, but not others by adding the room id as a suffix. `name=\"selectedroom".$sub_row['room_id']."\"`

I recommend changing your form element names, in order to submit as an array of rooms to and changing the `guestform.php` script to accept the array of values.

```
<form>
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        <input name="room[<?php echo $row['room_id']; ?>][total_adult]"/>
    <?php } ?>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button
</form>
```

**guestform.php** no longer needs to query the database. Example: https://3v4l.org/BZpEP

```
if (!empty($_POST['room'])) {
    $rooms = array_flter((array) $_POST['room'], function($room) {
        return !empty($room['qty']);
    });

    //...

    $count = 0;
    foreach ($rooms as $room_id => $room) {
            $_SESSION['room_id'][$count] = $room_id;
            $_SESSION['roomqty'][$count] = $room['qty'];
            $_SESSION['roomname'][$count] = $room['name'];
            $_SESSION['total_adult'][$count] = $room['total_adult'];
            $_SESSION['total_children'][$count] = $room['total_children'];
            $_SESSION['rate'][$count] = $room['rate'];
            $_SESSION['chrate'][$count] = $room['chrate'];

            //...
            $count++;
    }
}
```

---

However, there are also a significant amount of invalid HTML syntax issues in your code, which can break the HTML following the invalid syntax and cause rendering issues in the browser. This can cause Javascript to break, corrupted form data, or display problems.

I recommend separating your HTML and PHP code into simple `<div><?php echo $variable; ?></div>` style formatting instead.

This will make troubleshooting HTML related issues MUCH easier, since you're no longer having to track which text has been escaped or not and allow HTML and PHP syntax highlighters (like StackOverflow or PHPStorm) to parse your code.

List of issues that were found in the HTML.

> `<p>` elements are not capable of wrapping  `<h4>` and `<div>`
>   elements. `<p>` elements typically are not allowed to have other block
>   elements inside of them.
>
> `<img>` elements do not use a closing tag of `</img>`.
>
> HTML attributes were not being closed correctly `<select ...
>   style=\"width:100%; color:black; height:45px;\" ;\">\n"` results in
>   `<select style="";">`
>
> Closing `</p>` element missing opening tag

I updated your code with my suggestions and commented out the invalid HTML code using `<!-- -->` for easy referencing.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/auth.php';
// check available room
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT r.room_id, (r.total_room-br.total) AS availableroom 
FROM room AS r 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT roombook.room_id, SUM(roombook.totalroombook) AS total 
    FROM roombook 
    WHERE roombook.booking_id IN(
        SELECT b.booking_id as bookingID
        FROM booking AS b 
        WHERE 
        (b.checkin_date between '" . $datestart . "' AND '" . $dateend . "') 
        OR 
        (b.checkout_date between '" . $dateend . "' AND '" . $datestart . "')
    )
    GROUP BY roombook.room_id
) AS br
ON r.room_id = br.room_id");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { ?>
    <p>
        <b>Choose Your Room</b>
    </p>
    <hr class="line">
    <form action="guestform.php" method="post">
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($row['availableroom'] != null && $row['availableroom'] > 0) {
                $sub_result = mysqli_query($conn, 'select room.* from room where room.room_id = ' . $row['room_id'] . ' ');
                if (mysqli_num_rows($sub_result) > 0) {
                    while ($sub_row = mysqli_fetch_array($sub_result)) { ?>
                        <!-- <p> --><h4><?php echo $sub_row['room_name']; ?></h4><!-- </p> -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="large-4 columns">
                                <img src="<?php echo $sub_row['imgpath']; ?>"><!-- </img> -->
                                <p>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">Occupancy : </span> <?php echo $sub_row['occupancy']; ?><br>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">Size : </span> <?php echo $sub_row['size']; ?><br>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">View : </span> <?php echo $sub_row['view']; ?>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="large-4 columns">
                                <p>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">Total Adult</span>
                                </p>
                                <input type="text" name="room[<?php echo $sub_row['room_id']; ?>][total_adult]"><br>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">Total Children</span>
                                </p>
                                <input type="text" name="room[<?php echo $sub_row['room_id']; ?>][total_children]"><br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="large-4 columns">
                                <p>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">Rate : MYR </span>
                                </p>
                                <input type="text" name="room[<?php echo $sub_row['room_id']; ?>][rate]" value="<?php echo $sub_row['weekday']; ?>"><span class="fontgrey">/person</span><br>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">Rate : MYR </span>
                                </p>
                                <p> <!-- added p -->
                                    <input type="text" name="room[<?php echo $sub_row['room_id']; ?>][chrate]" value="<?php echo $sub_row['cweekday']; ?>"><span class="fontgrey">/person</span><br>
                                    <span style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $row['availableroom']; ?> room available</span>
                                </p>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="large-11 columns">
                                        <label class="fontcolor">
                                            <select class="no_of_room" name="room[<?php echo $sub_row['room_id']; ?>][qty]" id="room<?php echo $sub_row['room_id']; ?>" onChange="selection(<?php echo $sub_row['room_id']; ?>)" style="width:100%; color:black; height:45px;"  <!-- ;" -->>
                                            <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= $row['availableroom']; $i++) { ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="large-1 columns">
                                        <input type=hidden name="room[<?php echo $sub_row['room_id']; ?>][name]" id="room_name<?php echo $sub_row['room_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $sub_row['room_name']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    <?php }
                }
            } elseif ($row['availableroom'] == null) {
                $sub_result2 = mysqli_query($conn, 'select room.* from room where room.room_id = "' . $row['room_id'] . '"');
                if (mysqli_num_rows($sub_result2) > 0) {
                    while ($sub_row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sub_result2)) { ?>
                        <!-- <p> --><h4><?php echo $sub_row2['room_name']; ?></h4><!-- </p> -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="large-4 columns">
                                <img src="<?php echo $sub_row2['imgpath']; ?>"><!-- </img> -->
                                <p>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">Occupancy : </span> <?php echo $sub_row2['occupancy']; ?><br>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">Size : </span> <?php echo $sub_row2['size']; ?><br>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">View : </span> <?php echo $sub_row2['view']; ?>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="large-4 columns">
                                <p>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">Total Adult</span>
                                </p>
                                <input type="text" name="room[<?php echo $sub_row2['room_id']; ?>][total_adult]"><br>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">Total Children</span>
                                </p>
                                <input type="text" name="room[<?php echo $sub_row2['room_id']; ?>][total_children]"><br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="large-4 columns">
                                <p>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">Rate : MYR </span>
                                </p>
                                <input type="text" name="room[<?php echo $sub_row2['room_id']; ?>][rate]" value="<?php echo $sub_row2['weekday']; ?>"><span class="fontgrey">/person</span><br>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="fontgrey">Rate : MYR </span>
                                </p>
                                <p> <!-- added p -->
                                    <input type="text" name="room[<?php echo $sub_row2['room_id']; ?>][chrate]" value="<?php echo $sub_row2['cweekday']; ?>"><span class="fontgrey">/person</span><br>
                                <!-- <div> --> <span style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $sub_row2['total_room']; ?> room available</span><!-- </div> -->
                                </p>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="large-11 columns">
                                        <label class="fontcolor">
                                            <select class="no_of_room" name="room[<?php echo $sub_row2['room_id']; ?>][qty]" id="room<?php echo $sub_row2['room_id']; ?>" onChange="selection(<?php echo $sub_row2['room_id']; ?>)" style="width:100%; color:black; height:45px;">
                                                <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= $sub_row2['total_room']; $i++) { ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="large-1 columns">
                                        <input type=hidden name="room[<?php echo $sub_row2['room_id']; ?>][name]" value="<?php echo $sub_row2['room_name']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    <?php }
                }
            }
        } ?>
        <button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="hidden" style="display:none">Book</button>
    </form>
<?php }
```

Comment: Dear sir, at first i thought that form tag is the main problem in my code. because this problem start after editing the form tag not touching other code line. the code work properly before i add the end tag for form. because of my current status for my project already ahead from this i will be a headache if i change to your suggestion now. i will keep in mind for your advice

Comment: For future reader reminder, please keep in mind that invalid form element name is also main reason why your form is not working.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the update**

the answer for the main question is in general is yes

**For example**

Do not print end tag before any of your input line

```
print "<form action="" method ="post">";
if(isset ($_SESSION[something])) && ($_SESSION[$something] >0{
    if ($_SESSION[something] > 10) {
        print" <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\">";
        }
    print" </form>";

}
print" <input type=\"text\" name=\"number\">";
```

Do this instead,

```
print "<form action="" method ="post">";
if(isset ($_SESSION[something])) && ($_SESSION[$something] >0{
    if ($_SESSION[something] > 10) {
        print" <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\">";
        }


}
print" <input type=\"text\" name=\"number\">";
print" </form>";
```

**But for this specific code the form tag is correct,but the problem is within the input line and process code.**

**Input line**

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"total_adult".$sub_row['room_id']."\">
<input type=\"text\" name=\"total_children".$sub_row['room_id']."\" >
<input type=\"text\" name=\"rate".$sub_row['room_id']."\" value=\"".$sub_row2['weekday']."\">
<input type=\"text\" name=\"chrate".$sub_row['room_id']."\" value=\"".$sub_row2['cweekday']."\">
```

**Process code**

```
         $_SESSION['total_adult'][$count] = $_POST["total_adult".$row['room_id'].""];
         $_SESSION['total_children'][$count] = $_POST["total_children".$row['room_id'].""];
         $_SESSION['rate'][$count] = $_POST["rate".$row['room_id'].""];
         $_SESSION['chrate'][$count] = $_POST["chrate".$row['room_id'].""];
```